# Xamarin ios App is behaving strange in release mode,Which works as expected in debug Mode

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, release, debug-symbols

My Xamarin ios App is behaving strange in release mode,Which is working as expected in debug Mode

I have following line in one of the button handler

```
partial void OnClickStartBtn (UIKit.UIButton sender)
{
    string strCurrentImage = sender.CurrentImage.AccessibilityIdentifier;
}
```

Its giving the proper `AccessibilityIdentifier` string output in Debug Mode , But in Release mode Its Null and my application is crashing, 
 we should not use `AccessibilityIdentifier`  ? Or is there any fixes for release mode?

Answer (score 0):

I feel like you should not use `AccessibilityIdentifier` for what you are trying to accomplish.

If you are trying to identify the `UIButton` and take a different action depending on the button, use any of the following instead:

1. Use `UIButton.Tag`, an integer to identify each button.
2. Use a different click method for each button.
3. Use a better design pattern, such as the MVVM pattern. Your
   ViewModel would know the appropriate action to take. This one is
   best but probably would require you to restructure your application.